# How do update a table and it's associated join table in the same form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, join

I am building a website for a podcast. My tables are "episodes" and "guests" and a join table called "episodes_guests". "episodes" have and belong to many "guests". I have a form that updates the information of each episode, and am trying to let it update the guests associated with that episode as well (data stored in the join table), but can not figure it out.

I have been able to add a (form_for) form field that populates the associated guest information, but when i hit update these fields do not update the join table (I am not even sure if I'm outputting the information).

**This is the table from the episode controller 'edit' view**

```
<%= form_for(@episode) do |f| %>
<table summary="Episode form fields">
  <tr>
    <th> Episode ID </th>
    <td><%= f.text_field(:id) %></td>
  </tr>
  <%= f.fields_for :guests, @episode.guests.each do |g| %>
  <tr>
    <!-- I am trying to add a selector for guests -->
    <th>Guest: </th>
    <td>
          <%= g.text_area :last_name %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
      <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= f.submit("Update Episode") %>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

**Episode Model**

```
class Episode < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :guests
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guests
  scope:sorted, lambda {order("episode_number ASC")}
end
```

**Guest Model**

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :episodes

  scope:sorted, lambda {order("id ASC")}
end
```

**Episode controller**

```
class EpisodesController < ApplicationController

 def edit
    @episode = Episode.find(params[:id])
    @guests = @episode.guests.all
  end

  def update
    #Find a object using form parameters
    @episode = Episode.find(params[:id])
    @episode_guests = @episode.guests
    #Update the object
    if @episode.update_attributes(episode_params)
    #If the save succeeds, redirect to the show actions
    redirect_to(episode_path(@episode))
  else
    #If the save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
    render('edit')
  end
end

private

def episode_params
  params.require(:episode).permit(:id, :episode_number, :title, :guests, :file_name, :description, :date_released)
end

def guest_params
  params.require(:guest).permit(:id, :guest_id, :first_name, :last_name)
end
end
```

**Guest Controller**

```
class GuestsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    #Find a object using form parameters
    @guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
    #Update the object
    if @guest.update_attributes(guest_params)
    #If the save succeeds, redirect to the show actions
    redirect_to(guest_path(@guest))
  else
    #If the save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
    render('edit')
  end
end


private

def guest_params
  params.require(:guest).permit(:id, :guest_id, :first_name, :last_name)
end
end
```

My hope is to get to the point that i can input the guest id's into the form, click the update button, and have the guests associated with that episode updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a watch and a try.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised?autoplay=true

It should solve your issue. I would also suggest doing `has_many_through` instead of `has_and_belongs_to_many` as it is more flexible. The video talks about that too.

You could structure your data as follows:
`Guests` have many `Appearances` through `Episodes` and the inverse for `Episodes` to `Guests`.

This would let you look up `Guest.first.appearances` to see that Steve has appeared in 3 episodes or call `Episode.third.guests` and see that Steve, Susie and Ahmed were all on the episode.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working through this now. 
Could you explain why it should be

Guests have many Appearances through: :Episodes
instead of 
Guests have many Episodes through: :appearances?

Also do i need to have a model for appearances?

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong! It should be `guests` have many `episodes` through `appearances` and then the inverse is `episodes` have many `guests` through `appearances`.  You do need a model for `appearances` as it is your join model. It would replace your current `episode_guests` to me it makes better sense as a naming convention but you can call the model Dave if you like :)

Comment: haha okay i see! I've followed the railscast and I've got it 90% of the way there. Now I'm just getting an a console error "unpermitted parameter: :guest_ids" . I know this has something to do with strong parameters but i can't seem to work out the syntax to allow it. It would be under def episode_params in the episode controller right? Thank you for all your help so far.

Comment: You should just need to put `guest_ids: []` in the strong params of the `Episodes`controller. You are passing in an array of `ids` so hence the empty array syntax.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you for all the help Red Hendery!